# What exactly is "http://www.you.com"?

Tags: localhost, wamp

If I try to open a url such as "http://www.you.com", it directly goes to localhost as if I installed WAMP server on my computer, otherwise it shows **Unknown Host**.

Why is it happening?

Comment: I get error 503 when I go.

Comment: Because you have an entry in your `/etc/hosts` file that looks something like `127.0.0.1  www.you.com` perhaps? What do you mean with `otherwise` on another computer?